# Beautifulsoup4 does not show the table content

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautifulsoup4 in order to scrape info in github. However, whenever I try to get the data inside a table the program just returns table tags of opening and close.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import lxml

source = requests.get("https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org/find/master").text
soup = bs(source, "lxml")
tbody = soup.find("tbody", class_= "js-tree-finder-results js-navigation-container js-active-navigation-container")
print(tbody)
```

This is what it returns:

```
<tbody class="js-tree-finder-results js-navigation-container js-active-navigation-container">
</tbody>
```

And here is the source code from the github link (It is just the part that concerns the issue):

```
 <tbody class="js-tree-finder-results js-navigation-container js-active-navigation-container"><tr class="js-navigation-item tree-browser-result" aria-selected="false">
              <td class="icon"><svg class="octicon octicon-chevron-right" viewBox="0 0 8 16" version="1.1" width="8" height="16" aria-hidden="true"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.5 8l-5 5L1 11.5 4.75 8 1 4.5 2.5 3l5 5z"></path></svg></td>
              <td class="icon"><svg class="octicon octicon-file" viewBox="0 0 12 16" version="1.1" width="12" height="16" aria-hidden="true"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6 5H2V4h4v1zM2 8h7V7H2v1zm0 2h7V9H2v1zm0 2h7v-1H2v1zm10-7.5V14c0 .55-.45 1-1 1H1c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1V2c0-.55.45-1 1-1h7.5L12 4.5zM11 5L8 2H1v12h10V5z"></path></svg></td>
              <td>
                <a class="css-truncate-target js-navigation-open js-tree-finder-path" href="https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org/blob/master/.gitattributes">.gitattributes</a>
              </td>
            </tr><tr class="js-navigation-item tree-browser-result" aria-selected="false">
              <td class="icon"><svg class="octicon octicon-chevron-right" viewBox="0 0 8 16" version="1.1" width="8" height="16" aria-hidden="true"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.5 8l-5 5L1 11.5 4.75 8 1 4.5 2.5 3l5 5z"></path></svg></td>
              <td class="icon"><svg class="octicon octicon-file" viewBox="0 0 12 16" version="1.1" width="12" height="16" aria-hidden="true"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6 5H2V4h4v1zM2 8h7V7H2v1zm0 2h7V9H2v1zm0 2h7v-1H2v1zm10-7.5V14c0 .55-.45 1-1 1H1c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1V2c0-.55.45-1 1-1h7.5L12 4.5zM11 5L8 2H1v12h10V5z"></path></svg></td>
              <td>
                <a class="css-truncate-target js-navigation-open js-tree-finder-path" href="https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org/blob/master/.gitignore">.gitignore</a>
              </td>
            </tr></tbody>
```

I have already tried to use different parsers and also I tried to use urblib3 instead of requests to get the source code but either ways give me the same result.

Comment: access the .text property i.e. tbody.text

Comment: the table and table content are created with javascript, which beautifulsoup cannot generate, you may want to look into libraries like Selenium, or PhantomJS to get the javascript table content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably You have search wrong `class` attribute value.Try the below `class` attribute value.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import lxml

source = requests.get("https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org/find/master").text
soup = bs(source, "lxml")
tbody = soup.find("tbody", class_= "js-tree-browser-result-template")
print(tbody)
```

Output:

```
    <tbody class="js-tree-browser-result-template" hidden="">
    <tr class="js-navigation-item tree-browser-result">
    <td class="icon"><svg aria-hidden="true" class="octicon octicon-chevron-right" height="16" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 8 16" width="8"><path d="M7.5 8l-5 5L1 11.5 4.75 8 1 4.5 2.5 3l5 5z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></td>
    <td class="icon"><svg aria-hidden="true" class="octicon octicon-file" height="16" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 12 16" width="12"><path d="M6 5H2V4h4v1zM2 8h7V7H2v1zm0 2h7V9H2v1zm0 2h7v-1H2v1zm10-7.5V14c0 .55-.45 1-1 1H1c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1V2c0-.55.45-1 1-1h7.5L12 4.5zM11 5L8 2H1v12h10V5z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></td>
    <td>

<a class="css-truncate-target js-navigation-open js-tree-finder-path" href="/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org/blob/master"></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
source = requests.get("https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org/find/master").text
soup = bs(source, "lxml")
tbody = soup.find_all('tbody')[0]
print(tbody)
```